# AngularJs Resource Json Error

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-resource

user.json File has just one entry:

```
{ 
    "id": 1, 
    "protocol": "http", 
    "ip": "255.255.255.0", 
    "port": "80",
    "userName": "usemanager", 
    "password": "password", 
    "diskPath": "D:nwjs"
}
```

Factory Code:

```
duseApp.factory('duseConnect', function ($resource) {
    return $resource("user.json");
});
```

Controller Code:

```
duseApp.controller("duseLoginController", function ($scope,duseConnect,  
    $location) {
        var user = duseConnect.get({id: 1});
        console.log(user);
        console.log(user.id);
    });
```

User Gets Listed.
But `console.log(user.id); is undefined`.
Why is it so?

OutPut of `console.log(user);`

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLBfT.png)

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(user);`

Comment: `code`l  
{
$promise:f

$resolved:true
diskPath:"D:nwjs"
id:1
ip:"255.255.255.0"
password:"password"
port:"80"
protocol:"http"
userName:"fusemanager"
__proto__:Object
}`code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your factory is returning promise and in that case you need to extract data from the promise.

```
duseConnect.get({id: 1}).then (function(user) {
   console.log(user);
   console.log(user.id);
});
```

Comment: Getting Error => TypeError: duseConnect.get(...).then is not a function(…)

Comment: This is working.`fuseConnect.get({id: 1}).$promise.then(function (user) {
        console.log(user.id);
        console.log(user.userName);
    });`

Answer (score 0):

The return of $resource is a resource "class" object with methods for the default set of resource actions optionally extended with custom actions. The default set contains these actions:

```
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} 
};
```

The way of using it could be:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
var user = User.get({userId:123}, function() {
  user.abc = true;
  user.$save();
})
```

In your case you can do something like:

```
duseApp.controller("duseLoginController", function ($scope,duseConnect,  
    $location) {
        var user = duseConnect.get({id: 1}, function (response) {);
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.id);
    }});
```